# Linear algebra - Prove the existence of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to get my mind around this  problem but even though i might know the solution, the logical path of my thoughts seems to be wrong.

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be subspaces of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ respectively. If $V$ is a finite dimension vector space and if it holds:
>   $$\dim Q + \dim P = \dim V$$
>   prove there exists a linear mapping $L: V \to W$ such that $\ker L = P$ and $\operatorname{im} L=Q$.

Now, this seems like an awfully easy task, especially if you remember that the sum of rank and defect of a linear mapping is equal to the dimension of the domain. But the problem here is that every solution i have begins with "Let's assume such mapping exists", which seems like a logical fallacy.

It's very hard to express the solution in the "language of linear algebra" and mathematical formalism :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $B_0$ be a basis for $P$, and extend it to a basis $B$ for $V$. Let $C$ be a basis for $Q$. Use $C$ to define $L$ on $B$, then use linearity to extend $L$ to $V$. If you need a further hint, mouse over the spoiler-protected block below.

> Note that $|B\setminus B_0|=|C|$.

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not understand. Why does that imply there MUST exist such a linear mapping.

Comment: @Transcendental: If $m=\dim Q$, let $B\setminus B_0=\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ and $C=\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$, and for $k=1,\ldots,m$ let $L(v_k)=w_k$. Let $L(v)=0_W$ for each $v\in B_0$. This defines $L$ on $B$, a basis for $V$, so linearity uniquely determines $L(v)$ for each $v\in V$. Now just check that $L$ has the required properties.